# What method creates the object in a Django class-based CreateView?

Tags: django, django-views

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297820/django-forms-with-get-or-create) shows how to use get_or_create with django forms. It will work fine for me because the model in question has no unique constraints other than the pk. But it looks to me like it's not using the generic CreateView, which I'd like to stick to if I can.

I presume the best way to emulate this in a CreateView is to override whichever method actually saves an object to the database but I can't find where that's happening in the source code. Am I missing something obvious or have I misunderstood how this is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateView` inherits from [`ModelFormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#modelformmixin). Override the [`form_valid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) method to change the behaviour when the form is valid.

You can see the [code for the `form_valid` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.4/django/views/generic/edit.py#L123) on GitHub. The default behaviour is described in the docs as:

> **`form_valid(form)`**
>   Saves the form instance, sets the current object for the view, and redirects to `get_success_url()`.